# Zoom out in IE by CSS or JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I tried many ways to accomplish zooming on the body tag by CSS, some posts do suggest `-ms-zoom: 150%` on IE, but it is not working.

```
body { 
    -ms-zoom: 150%;
    zoom: 1.5;
    zoom: 150%;
}
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    document.body.style.zoom = "150%";
});
```

All these methods are working on chrome and firefox, however they do not work in any IE browsers, the content do not fit into the viewport. It is not responsive in IE, I have tried

```
<meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

It does not work  the same way as when you just simply zoom in or zoom out by pressing ctrl and plus/minus on the keyboard in IE.

Anyone came across this?

Comment: what version of IE ?

Comment: any versions, not edge. IE11, IE10, IE9, IE8